# Select by key from another list in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose I have two objects:

```
class Apple
{
     public int ID {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
     public string Color {get;set;}
}

class UsedApple
{
     public int ID {get;set;}
     public int AppleID {get;set;}
}
```

How can I select all used Apples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join.aspx) method (same as inner join in SQL):

```
IEnumerable<Apple> query = from ua in usedApples
                           join a in apples on ua.AppleID equals a.ID
                           select a;
```